# Comparing data in Textbox with data in a Table in unicode (VBA Access 2016)

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I've some problems when I use `if` condition to compare data in a text box with data in a table in unicode(Khmer language) in vba access 2016. The data in the text box and table were different,but the condition is true.
Does someone have an answer or can explain my problem to me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will need to provide some example of your problem. Please see [this regarding asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to compare using the *StrComp* function:

```
Match = (StrComp(onestring, anotherstring, vbBinaryCompare) = 0)
```

or in a query:

```
Match: StrComp([onefield], [anotherfield], 0) = 0
```